# How to convert json into byte format in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, authentication

I am working on a app that will take a users name and password, authenticate it and log them in. So what I am doing is taking the inputs and converting them into JSON. But before I send it they need to be in byte format for it to work.

So far this is what I have.

```
@IBOutlet var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!


let json: [String: AnyObject] = ["name:": name.text! as AnyObject,
                                     "password:": password.text! as AnyObject]

    do{

        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

        //this is just an example website
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            let JSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)

            print(JSON)
        }

        task.resume()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

I know there is something called JSON marshaling but not sure if that exist in Swift.

How do I convert the JSON file into byte format in Swift?

Comment: change `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)` to `var request = URLRequest(url: url!)` and `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)` to `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)`

Comment: also make sure you add the complete url (including the scheme), for instance "h t t p : //www.website.com"

Comment: declare your json as `[String: Any]`

Comment: change your dictionary keys `"name:"` and `"password:"` to `"name"`and  `"password"`

Comment: What you mean byte format? Are you need size of total JSON data?